# Define function to test arguments and set value to 0 (application 0 Log [0] = 0)

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have an expression that has the form

```
f1[a, b, c] Log[ f2[a, b, c] ]
```

Now if `f1[a,b,c]` and `f2[a,b,c]` evaluate to 0, then we have 0 Log[0], which I want to set to 0. I can achieve this by creating the following function:

```
g[0, 0 | 0.] = 0;
g[x_, y_] := x Log[y];
SetAttributes[g, Listable]
```

which will evaluate what I want, but set the value to 0 if both `f1[a,b,c]` and `f2[a,b,c]` are 0

However, sometimes, `f1[a,b,c]` and `f2[a,b,c]` are:

1. approximately zero (in the order of 10^-8, which can be handled via a `Chop` command), and
2. negative (~ - 10^-8).

I am not sure how to handle negative occurrences. I.e. in the instance we have 10^-5 Log[- 10^-8], this should be set to zero. I imagine this can be achieved by an edit to the function `g`, but how?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
ClearAll @ g
SetAttributes[g, Listable]
Off[Infinity::indet]

g[0, 0 | 0.] := 0
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := Re[x Log @ y]
g[__] := 0

g[10^-5, -10.^-8]
```

-0.000184207

```
g[2, 40.]
```

7.37776

```
g[0, 0.]
```

0

```
g[0 Log @ 0]
```

0

```
g[0, Log @ 0]
```

0

Answer (score 1):

I would define my own Log like e.g.:

```
ClearAll[myLog]
SetAttributes[myLog, Listable]
myLog[x_] = If[x <= 0, 0, Log[x]];
```

Now zero arguments are defined:

```
0 myLog[0]

0
```

Neither do 10^-8 and -10^-8 pose any problems:

```
10^-8 myLog[10^-8] 
10^-8 myLog[-10^-8]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: the function I am trying to evaluate should be real. The second use example you show has an imaginary output, which is precisely the problem. The outcome needs to therefore be set to zero, which I would like to achieve by changing the definition of `myLog`

Comment: I changed the definition to ensure that a negative arg of myLog results in zero.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than define your function directly, you could define it based on the result of the log expression.

```
myLogTerm[coeff_, arg_, chop_] :=
  With[
    {term = coeff Log[arg]},
    If[Norm[term] > chop, term, 0, 0]]
```